# Fair coin to produce a normally-distributed random variable in finite number of throws

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I was wondering whether it is possible to use a fair coin (i.e. one with equal probabilities of landing heads or tails up) to produce a random variable that is normally distributed? In particular -- and this is the difficult thing -- I was wondering whether it is possible to do so in a finite number of coin tosses?

I know that in the limit of infinite samples, I could use the sample mean and the Lindberg-Levy Central Limit Theorem to produce such a variable. However, my question here is -- is it possible to do so in a finite number of tosses?

Note: I know that I can *approximate* a normally-distributed random variable after not many tosses. However, here I want something that is exactly normally distributed.

Answer (score 3):

The normal distribution has support over an infinite number of values.
In a finite number of tosses of a coin there are only finitely many
possible outcomes.

That is merely one of several reasons why
you cannot generate a normal distribution
with a finite number of coin tosses.

Comment: Right, but caveat: one could generate some distribution that takes an infinite (countable) number of values by throwing a coin a finite _average_ number of tosses. For example, a geometric distribution.

Comment: @leonbloy I saw "finite" in the question and assumed "bounded." If unbounded is OK, you _can_ generate some infinite distributions. The thing that really kills this idea (among the "several reasons") is that even with unbounded finite tosses, the coin can only generate discrete distributions, and the normal distributions are continuous. Perhaps I should modify the answer.

Comment: IMHO, the idea is there so you can leave the answer as it is. +1.